# Segmentation Fault in Unit test

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc

I tested my C code with the unity function for unit test. It showed the error and a segmentation fault? Is it usual to have a segmentation fault after a unit test failure? or it is something wrong with my code?
Because, when I correct the error, it run successfully

```
time.c

//gets start time and duration in 24 hour format and returns the total of the two in 24 hour clock


int add_time(int starttime, int duration)
{
     int startHour = starttime / 100;
     int startMinute = starttime % 100;
     int durationHour = duration / 100;
     int durationMinute = duration % 100;

     int finishHour = startHour + durationHour;
     int finishMinute = startMinute + durationMinute;

     if(finishMinute > 59)
     {
         finishMinute %= 60;
        finishHour++; 
    }

     finishHour %= 24;

     return (finishHour * 100 + finishMinute);  
}

//given end and start time, calculates the duration in 24 hour clock (duration is always less than one day) 
int duration(int endtime, int starttime)
{
     if(endtime < starttime)
         endtime += 2400;

     int endHour = endtime / 100;
     int endMinute = endtime % 100;
     int startHour = starttime / 100;
     int startMinute = starttime % 100;

     int durationMinute = endMinute - startMinute;
     int durationHour = endHour - startHour;

     if(durationMinute < 0)
     {
        durationMinute += 60;
        durationHour--;
     }

    return (durationHour * 100 + durationMinute);

}
```

testtime.c

```
#include "unity.h"
#include "time.c"
setUp()
{
}
tearDown()
{
}
void firstTest()
{
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(1, add_time(2359, 2));
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(1530, add_time(1215, 315));
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_INT(2215, add_time(2345, 2230));
}

int main()
{
    firstTest();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is added to the question

Comment: Same issue, Tried GNU GDB , __longjmp() at ../sysdeps/x86-64/__longjmp.S:67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't correct to say that it is usual to have a segfault after a unit test fails. However, it is *usual* to expect seg-faults and other errors when your code is wrong.

You can't really generalize about a segfault in relation to a particular framework or technique (unit testing in this case). Until you investigate the cause of the error, all you know is that the error happened.

Try running your incorrect code in a debugger and figuring out exactly where the segfault occurred? Is it in your code, or in the unit test framework?

Comment: I compiled and ran the code you posted without errors. Did you post the working version or the version that causes segfaults?

Comment: This is the version with segmentation fault, I ran the corrected version and didn't get any errors

Comment: So I want to know whether the segmentation fault is from the unity test or from the code

Comment: Yes. Compile your code with debugging symbols turned on to find out where it occurred. To do this with GCC add -g to compile command.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Unity for testing.
Try to make your main method like this:

```
int main()
{
   UNITY_BEGIN();
    if (TEST_PROTECT()) {
      RUN_TEST(firstTest);
    }
   UNITY_END();
}
```